# Generic avro schema for geojson

Tags: geojson, avro, apache-nifi

Which is the way to define a generic avro array for one field? The case is for geojson data, the value for coordinates is always an array, but depending on the type, the array structure may be different:

> 3.1.2. Point For type "Point", the "coordinates" member is an array of single position.
>
> 3.1.3. MultiPoint For type "MultiPoint", the "coordinates" member is an array of positions.
>
> 3.1.4. LineString For type "LineString", the "coordinates" member is an array of two or more positions.
>
> 3.1.5. MultiLineString For type "MultiLineString", the "coordinates" member is an array of LineString coordinate arrays.
>
> 3.1.6. Polygon o For type "Polygon", the "coordinates" member MUST be an array of linear ring coordinate arrays.
>
> 3.1.7. MultiPolygon For type "MultiPolygon", the "coordinates" member is an array of Polygon coordinate arrays.

Comment: why you want to create a unique schema? anyway you will need to figure out what type of "point" you have to access the data. Anyway this could be done creating different nullables fields in the avro schema with each point type, is not an option?

Comment: The unique schema is required when dealing with pipelines from generic geometry shapes, for example, indexing geoshapes in elasticsearch, the type is generic and I could run queries like "all geometries contained into this geometry" no matter the shape type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to define the array as an array of custom complex types, and define a custom type using `record` for each possible element type. You might also be able to declare the array as an array of `map`s with `string` values?